# Click an image, get coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a standard HTML image tag with an image in it, 100 by 100 pixels in size. I want people to be able to click the image and for that to pass the X and Y that they click into a function.

The coordinates need to be relative to the image top and left.

Comment: This thread answers exactly the same <a href="http://bytes.com/forum/thread507079.html">question</a> With more info <a href="http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position">here</a>

Answer (score 5):

I think you're talking about:

```
<input id="info" type="image">
```

When submitted, there are form values for the x and y coordinate based on the input element id (`info.x` and `info.y` in this case).

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1

Answer (score 1):

from what you describe you should register to the image mouse event, for this case you should have the image mouse button event.

at the function you should use

```
Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition( this );
```

that will give you the mouse position according to the top left point int pixels.

than at the `mousePoint` you can print the X and Y information.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the canvas with your image and it will work the same

```js
let img = document.getElementById("canvas");

img.x = img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
img.y = img.getBoundingClientRect().top;

function click(e) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "X coords: " + (e.clientX - img.x) + "<br> Y coords: " + (e.clientY - img.y);
}

img.addEventListener("click", click);
```

```html
<!--- Like a image --->
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<p id="output"></p>
```