# how to allow user to put images on top of another image in html?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I Want to have an image of a car, and when a user clicks a spot on the car, I drop an x image or a circle image on that spot. I need to save the spot where they clicked so when they come back I display it in the same spot.

What is the best way to do this in html?

Should I use an image with other images overlaid on top of it?

Should I use html5?

Anybody know of any working examples of a similar nature?

Want to use js, html5, etc to make this work on iphone safari (not native app). App is ruby on rails, so I could make use of some server side features, but would prefer to leverage as much in html/css if possible.

Comment: are you limited to only client-side technologies like javascript, html, and css?

Comment: yes, will edit to clarify, thanks, goal is to do this on safari for iphone ideally using html5, js and iui (or other similar)

Comment: As a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461/click-an-image-get-coordinates and http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: I don't understand why when I ask a good question and get a great answer you guys would close the question, this is just silly! My other question that you have closed has the most views of all my questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `canvas` element to do this. The `canvas` element allow you to draw images and shapes to it.

To store and retrieve clicks you can use *Web Storage* (`localStorage`).

For example - load the image and paint it to canvas:

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/mSHCC/)**

**HTML**:

```
<canvas id="demo" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
/// get context for canvas, cache dimension
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,

    img = new Image(); /// the image we want to load

/// when done go draw existing marks and start listening for clicks
img.onload = function() {

    renderMarks();

    demo.onclick = function(e) {

        /// convert mouse coord relative to canvas
        var rect = demo.getBoundingClientRect(),
            x = e.clientX - rect.left,
            y = e.clientY - rect.top;

        /// store mark
        addMark(x, y);

        /// redraw everything
        renderMarks();
    }
}
```

These are the main functions, this first renders existing marks to canvas on top of the image:

```
function renderMarks() {

    /// re-draw image which also serves to clear canvas    
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    /// get existing marks from localStorage
    var marks = localStorage.getItem('marks'),
        i = 0;

    /// if any, render them all
    if (marks !== null) {

        /// localStorage can only store strings 
        marks = JSON.parse(marks);

        /// set color and line width of circle
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;

        /// iterate marks and draw each one
        for(;i < marks.length; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(marks[i][0], marks[i][1], 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}
```

This adds a mark to the collection:

```
function addMark(x, y) {

    /// get existing marks or initialize
    var marks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('marks') || '[]');

    /// add mark
    marks.push([x, y]);

    /// update storage
    localStorage.setItem('marks', JSON.stringify(marks));
}
```

(The code can be optimized in various ways but I made it to show the basic principles).

If you now navigate away from the page and come back you will see the marks are rendered again (disclaimer: jsfiddle may or may not give the same page so test locally/in "real" page to be sure).

The circles here can be anything, an image, a different shape and so forth.

To clear the marks simply call:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

or if you store other data as well:

```
localStorage.removeItem('marks');
```

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create new images for each spot and when the user click you substitute the original image by the new one. You can do that using CSS or jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you are interested in showing areas or the exact x/y coordinates, an image [<map>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) might be of use.

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108406/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-interactive-image-map-with-jquery) stackoverflow question.

I have no working example to show, but I think this qualifies as *similar in nature*. I am not sure how you'd save the info for recalling state (coming back same session or days/months later?).

I hope this is of some use.